# PHP Unzip function works fine, but not if you call it from httpdocs/

Tags: php

I'm kinda stuck with a problem and i hope someone here can shine some light.

I am using some functions to unzip a .zip file and its folders, which works fine. But if i try to use the function from any other directory it doesn't seem to work or doesn't seem to create the folder dirs and write the files.

I'm using the following code to unzip a .zip file.

```
<?PHP error_reporting(e_all);

include("../../includes/config.php");


/**
 * Unzip the source_file in the destination dir
 *
 * @param   string      The path to the ZIP-file.
 * @param   string      The path where the zipfile should be unpacked, if false the directory of the zip-file is used
 * @param   boolean     Indicates if the files will be unpacked in a directory with the name of the zip-file (true) or not (false) (only if the destination directory is set to false!)
 * @param   boolean     Overwrite existing files (true) or not (false)
 * 
 * @return  boolean     Succesful or not
 */

function unzip($src_file, $dest_dir=false, $create_zip_name_dir=true, $overwrite=true)
{
  if ($zip = zip_open($src_file))
  {
    if ($zip)
    {
      $splitter = ($create_zip_name_dir === true) ? "." : "/";
      if ($dest_dir === false) $dest_dir = substr($src_file, 0, strrpos($src_file, $splitter))."/";

      // Create the directories to the destination dir if they don't already exist
      create_dirs($dest_dir);

      // For every file in the zip-packet
      while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
      {
        // Now we're going to create the directories in the destination directories

        // If the file is not in the root dir
        $pos_last_slash = strrpos(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "/");
        if ($pos_last_slash !== false)
        {
          // Create the directory where the zip-entry should be saved (with a "/" at the end)
          create_dirs($dest_dir.substr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), 0, $pos_last_slash+1));
        }

        // Open the entry
        if (zip_entry_open($zip,$zip_entry,"r"))
        {

          // The name of the file to save on the disk
          $file_name = $dest_dir.zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

          // Check if the files should be overwritten or not
          if ($overwrite === true || $overwrite === false && !is_file($file_name))
          {
            // Get the content of the zip entry
            $fstream = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            file_put_contents($file_name, $fstream );
            // Set the rights
            chmod($file_name, 0777);
            echo "save: ".$file_name."<br />";
          }

          // Close the entry
          zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }      
      }
      // Close the zip-file
      zip_close($zip);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

/**
 * This function creates recursive directories if it doesn't already exist
 *
 * @param String  The path that should be created
 * 
 * @return  void
 */

function create_dirs($path)
{
  if (!is_dir($path))
  {
    $directory_path = "";
    $directories = explode("/",$path);
    array_pop($directories);

    foreach($directories as $directory)
    {
      $directory_path .= $directory."/";
      if (!is_dir($directory_path))
      {
        //mkdir($directory_path);

        my_ftp_mkdir2('httpdocs/templates/temp/', $directory_path);

        //chmod($directory_path, 0777);
      }
    }
  }
}

/* CHMOD with FTP */

function my_ftp_mkdir2 ($path, $dir) {
    $server = "ftp.domainname.com";

    // Connect to FTP server
    $connection = ftp_connect ($server);

    // Login on FTP server
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "password";
    $result = ftp_login ($connection, $user, $pass);

    if ((!$connection) || (!$result)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Go to the dir thats been given
    if (!@ftp_chdir ($connection, $path)) {
        ftp_close($connection); // close FTP connection
        return false;
    }

    // Create the map and set the rights
    if (!@ftp_mkdir($connection, $dir)) {
        ftp_close($connection); // close FTP connection
        return false;    
    }

    $chmod_cmd = "CHMOD 0777 " . $dir;
    $chmod = ftp_site($connection, $chmod_cmd);

    ftp_close($connection); // close FTP connection

    return true;
}



if (!unzip("../user1/test2.zip", false, true, true)) {
    echo 'The file has failed to be unzipped!';
} else {
    echo 'The file has been unzipped!';
}


?>
```

Now this works great.

But im running this file in a test dir which is the following:
httpdocs/templates/temp/unzip.php

The file called test2.zip is located in:
httpdocs/templates/user1/test2.zip

So when i run the script it makes the following:
httpdocs/templates/user1/test2/index.html
httpdocs/templates/user1/test2/img/
etc etc..

But when i run this script from the httpdocs/ directory it says its has been unzipped but doesnt create any dirs or whatsoever.

My PHP has safemode on thats why i used FTP to chmod the dirs to 777 for test purpose.

So when i run this script in httpdocs/unzip.php

i call the function like this.

```
<?php
if (!unzip("templates/user1/test2.zip", false, true, true)) {
    echo 'The file has failed to be unzipped!';
} else {
    echo 'The file has been unzipped!';
}
?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, i hope someone can help me out with some good advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the owner of httpdocs to your webserver's user (for apache its www-data usually)

```
chown www-data:www-data /path/to/htttpdocs -R
```

Note: I guess you need access yourself to the files so exchange the first www-data with your username e.g user123:www-data

Note2: Check your webserver's error log you'll find your exact error message there. I can only guess that its a permission denied problem (Apache standart path is /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Note3: Safemode is removed in PHP 5.4 I would suggest you to update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the owner of httpdocs has already been set to the webservers user and doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Try using an absolute path in your function call.

Comment: @Adriaan have you found some usefull information in the error log?

Comment: I've tried this with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but also gives the message the zip is extracted but with no result of any created dirs...

I've checked the error log which displays some errors like this:
PHP Warning: file_put_contents() ..etcetc.. on line 56
PHP Warning: chmod() ..etcetc.. on line 58

line 56:

file_put_contents($file_name, $fstream );

line 58
chmod($file_name, 0777);

Comment: If you take a deeper look into the error log and those messages you'll find your problem

Comment: I read things like this: [Tue Apr 24 09:19:33 2012] [error] [client 114.79.29.131] PHP Warning: file_put_contents() [<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: Unable to access templates/user1/test/img1/ in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/mailings/httpdocs/unzip.php on line 56 

I still can't find the problem though, because in the other dir it is working perfectly without any problems.

I think the problem is that it doesn't create the dirs somehow and thats why php throws the error like above.. any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

me would do it using absolute paths &

```
mkdir($abspathdir,0777)
```

(& umask after to reset permissions)

probably neater & faster  (?) any reason to open a ftp connection to create new folders ?

to debug add a

```
echo $abspathdir,'<br/>';
```

before the mkdir so to check which directories are (trying to be) created. then if path is correct indeed but dir is not created it can be only a permission problem on the parent folder.

Comment: If i use mkdir it creates the dir but it sets the owner as apache and doesn't chmod it with the good permissions, thats why i had to use the ftp function. I guess mkdir isn't working properly because safemode is ON, thats why i worked around it by using the FTP function.

Comment: "    Note: When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the directory in which the script is operating has the same UID (owner) as the script that is being executed." http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php  also you could try the pclzip lib

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But all my dirs have the owner UID.